# play-framework router resource

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, router

dumb question on my second day trying to learn play framework...  in over my head still, but I'm stumped and can't figure out where to find the right docs to understand the libraries in use better.  searching playframework.com/documentation just turns up links to the example I was trying to copy in the first place.

I'm modifying the basic play-scala template, and I'm trying to follow the examples in these two links to get a javascript router in an action to work...

link1 - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaJavascriptRouting

link2 - http://semisafe.com/coding/2015/03/31/play_basics_templates_and_ajax.html

I've got this in my main controller...  and I get a compile error error stating "***not found: value Routes***".

I'm hoping this is something as simple as the libraries having changed and routes.javascript._ not being the right path to Routes, but I can't figure out what is, since all the examples I find look similar to this.

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject() extends Controller {

  // def index ...

  def jsRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
    import routes.javascript._
    Ok(
      Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(            // problem is here
        routes.javascript.Tickets.ticketsAvailable
      )
    )
  }
}
```

I don't think these are relevant to the error...  but I'm following the examples and have the route and link setup as well....

in routes...

```
GET     /jsr/                       controllers.HomeController.jsRoutes
```

in main.scala.html...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.jsRoutes"></script>
```

Comment: Could you provide the compiler-message? Also, which version of the framework are you using? When searching via google you usually do not land on the right doc-version. Make sure you pick the right one on the top-right of the website. 

For example, here is the doc for the latest stable release (2.5), where the example already looks a little different: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting

Comment: yes, wrong version...  right in the url for the doc it said version 2.1 and I'm using 2.5.9.  embarrassing...  but thank you.  I'm guessing since play is such a mashup of scala and js and twirls that there isn't a scaladocs style documentation?

Comment: There you go: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.javascriptRouter$